# HashMap with consecutive Integers as keys vs. ArrayList

Tags: java, performance, arraylist, hashmap

I stumbled upon some code that uses `HashMap<Integer,HashMap<Integer, String>>` to store a large Excel table with typically >100.000 rows and 10 columns. Both columns and rows are consecutive integers. I would have  definitely used something like a `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>` instead.

So could there be any significant advantages of using the `HashMap`? Do you see any serious performance issues (both memory an runtime wise)?

Comment: No. The original author should have used a list.

Comment: The map approach (obviously) assumes a sparse matrix, in that not nearly all cells are filled. If all cells are filled then there's obvious overhead with using a map of maps.

Comment: @Kayaman You can achieve the same with null without throwing away iteration order

Comment: @Kayaman He said they were consecutive integers, which implies non-sparse. A map with keys 0,1,2,3,... is just a bad list.

Comment: @Michael then it looks like the verdict is in. Luckily developers have more memory than sense these days. They probably copy pasted the code from somewhere.

Comment: I would also prefer composite keys over nested maps in most cases. (See https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/250124/nested-maps-vs-combined-keys)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel to compelled to contribute an answer but credit should go to @Kayaman who saw the obvious and commented first.

The significant potential advantage you are looking for is **speed, flexibility and space-saving in the general case**.

Consider that you have a 3x3 range of 9 cells with top-left corner at cell A1 and then add a single new cell at ZZ49.  With any data structure that uses *linear allocation* of memory you suddenly need to grow memory by several orders of magnitude (~30,000 new empty cells), possibly (depending on data structure) rearranging already-stored cells and initialising a large number of never-to-be-used nulls (language/library implementations will have varying implementation details but similar wasteful disadvantages).

Would Excel itself keep arrays/arraylists sized to cover every cell in every worksheet/range?  Unlikely.  In your example the range of cells may not be sparsely populated but in principle and in general the number of cells that contain data in a spreadsheet is a tiny fraction of the maximum rectangular area allowed.  A hashmap (or "multidimensional hashmapping") is therefore not an unreasonable choice of data structure in a general approach to such a map-to-Excel problem, although you might have good reason for a different choice in your specific application.

Answer (score 0):

Declare a Class with the atributes from the table, for example:

```
public class anyClass(){
int grossValue;
int netValue;
}
```

So you can store this data in a list

```
ArrayList<AnyClass>
```